# How to send jar between jobs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having problem with copy artifacts plugin in jenkins. I can't copy jar from project to other project.

I wrote jenkinsfile in mainproject

```
#!groovy
    properties([
      [$class: 'CopyArtifactPermissionProperty', projectNames: 'subproject']
    ])

node() {

    stage('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('Assemble') {
        sh "./gradlew clean assemble"
    }

    stage('FatJar') {
        echo 'Create fatJar'
        sh "./gradlew fatJar"
    }
}

node() {
    stage('Starting subproject') {
        build job: 'p.smith/subproject/myBranch'
    }
}
```

Command 'sh "./gradlew fatJar"' creates jar in build/libs

i wrote jenkinsfile in subproject

```
properties([[$class: 'CopyArtifact', projectName: 'mainProject', filter: '*.jar']
    ])
 node() {
        stage('Checkout') {
            checkout scm
        }

        stage('Assemble') {
            sh "./gradlew clean assemble"
        }

        stage('Unit Test') {
            echo 'Unit tests'
        try {
            sh "./gradlew test"
        } catch (err) {
            throw err
        } finally {
            junit '**/build/test-results/*.xml'
        }
   }
}
```

I do not know what I did wrong. I mustn't set config in the project configuration pages, because config is generate with jenkinsfile or job dsl.

Maybe I don't have configured project who can copy artifacts (subproject)

Could someone help me with this problem? Thank you in advance, Peter

Comment: You should have something for the artifacts management like Artifactory or a maven repo, then you can publish/install the artifact in one job and just fetch it from the repo in the other.